# How to get web3 accounts in solc?

Tags: solidity, web3js

My blockchain project with solc version ^0.4.6 . Has been throwing errors when given the command of being web3.eth.accounts.

`web3.eth.accounts`

> Uncaught Error: Invalid JSON RPC response: undefined
> at Object.InvalidResponse (E:\techdot-master\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\errors.js:38:16)
> at HttpProvider.send (E:\techdot-master\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\httpprovider.js:91:22)
> at RequestManager.send (E:\techdot-master\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\requestmanager.js:58:32)
> at Eth.get [as accounts] (E:\techdot-master\node_modules\web3\lib\web3\property.js:107:62).

I have tried reading the docs and tried other commands. Still unable to resolve the issue!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Invalid JSON RPC response" means you are not connected to the node. In order to connect to a node, you need a provider. You can get an infura account and create a provider HdWalletProvider

```
const HDWalletProvider = require("@truffle/hdwallet-provider");
const provider = new HDWalletProvider({
  mnemonic: {
    phrase: metamask_mnemonic, 
  },
  providerOrUrl: ropsten_network,//infura endpoint here
});
```

Or if you are using ganache-cli

```
const ganache = require('ganache-cli');
const provider = ganache.provider()
```

Then create web3

```
   const web3 = new Web3(provider);
```

I think instead of accounts, should be `getAccounts`

```
   const accounts = await web3.eth.getAccounts();
```

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using ehtersjs, with it everything is a lot easier.